# XCode вылетает после начала билда

Tags: xcode, macos

Скачал XCode версии 11.2.5 (не говорите мне про обновления). Создал проект, после запуска приложения на стадии:

[image: стадия]

у меня тупо пропадает мышка и через секунд 5 показывается окно входа в аккаунт MacOS. После входа XCode перезапускается и так каждый раз

Пробовал решения с [этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34451126/xcode-crashes-on-launch), но ничего не помогает.

Такое же происходит со Swift проектом:

[image: swift]